# Tabularx with tikz and text starting at top of the cell

Tags: tables, tabularx

I'm working with `tabularx` where I'm arranging pictures of limits on the left cells and I want to type the solutions on the right side.

This is the code for the table, but I'm having a hard time arranging it so that all the text (and pictures) start at the top of the cell. I have seen `[t]` and `\toprule` in answers but it doesn't seem to work, or I don't know where to put it for it to work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in,landscape]{geometry}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pgfplots} % for graphs
\usepackage{enumitem} %for abc lists%
\setlength{\columnsep}{1 in} % for column spacing%
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1} %for toc level --> up to and including subsections%
\raggedcolumns % to make column heights uneven
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}


\begin{document}
\begin{multicols*}{2}

\begin{tabularx}{0.425\textwidth}{ X X }

Above picture & Above explanation \\

A) \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5] %Quad 01%
\begin{axis}[ xmin=0, xmax=3, ymin=0, ymax=3]
\draw[color=gray] (-5,0) -- (5,0);
\draw[color=gray] (0,-5) -- (0,5);
\addplot[domain=0:3, line width=5pt, samples=300] {x+1};
\filldraw[fill=white, ultra thick, line width=2pt](1,2) circle (0.1); % dot
\draw[dashed, line width=5pt, color=green] ( 0,-5 ) -- ( 0,5 ); % vertical
\draw[dashed, line width=5pt, color=green] ( -5,0 ) -- ( 5,0 ); % horizontal
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} 

&  

Explanation line 1



Explanation line 2

\\

Below picture  & Below explanation


\end{tabularx}


\end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please make your code snippet compilable by indicating which document class you employ and which packages must be loaded.

Comment: Here's the code that reflects the problems I'm having. (I have other code in the document but it not relevant to the question, I think?) I just made a new document and compiled it, so it should be okay.

Comment: `\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5,baseline=2.6cm]`?

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work (at least it gives me what I want visually. I don't foresee the code being more complicated than this, and so I think will work well.

Answer (score 3):

This is a solution that works even if the TikZ picture is different.

I have used the new package `tabularray` because is easiest to align the row text at the top.

I have given a name to the axis environment with `name = myaxis`, create a coordinate (which has no dimension) at 12pt lower than `myaxis.north` (you can use any position you like):

```
\coordinate (mycoor) at ([yshift=-12pt]myaxis.north);
```

and then I have used this coordinate as baseline: `baseline=(mycoor)`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{pgfplots} % for graphs
\usepackage{enumitem} %for abc lists%
\setlength{\columnsep}{1 in} % for column spacing%
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1} %for toc level --> up to and including subsections%
\raggedcolumns % to make column heights uneven
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}


\begin{document}
\begin{multicols*}{2}

\begin{tblr}{*2{X[l,h]}}
Above picture & Above explanation \\
A) \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5, baseline=(mycoor)] %Quad 01%
\begin{axis}[ xmin=0, xmax=3, ymin=0, ymax=3,name = myaxis]
\draw[color=gray] (-5,0) -- (5,0);
\draw[color=gray] (0,-5) -- (0,5);
\addplot[domain=0:3, line width=5pt, samples=300] {x+1};
\filldraw[fill=white, ultra thick, line width=2pt](1,2) circle (0.1); % dot
\draw[dashed, line width=5pt, color=green] ( 0,-5 ) -- ( 0,5 ); % vertical
\draw[dashed, line width=5pt, color=green] ( -5,0 ) -- ( 5,0 ); % horizontal
\end{axis}
\coordinate (mycoor) at ([yshift=-12pt]myaxis.north);
\end{tikzpicture} 
&  
{Explanation line 1\\
Explanation line 2}
\\
Below picture  & Below explanation
\end{tblr}
\end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```

[image]